# Need to truncate Razor HTML DisplayFor Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to truncate a text field that is sometimes extremely large or at other times it is null from the database i.e

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MainBiography)
```

and replace with three dots at the end.

I have tried the substring function but keep getting errors.

Any pointers, thanks!

Update:

The ... is not hugely important so I tried using

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MainBiography.Substring(0,10))
```

and get the following error codes:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2146233079 Message=Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions. Source=System.Web.Mvc –

Comment: Show us the code... What errors are you getting?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
  Source=System.Web.Mvc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're better off creating a different property in the model, to pick up the `MainBiography` and eventually cut it short.

Like this:

```
// This is your property (sampled)
public string MainBiography { get; set; }

//How long do you want your property to be at most ?
//(Best practice advices against magic numbers)
private int MainBiographyLimit = 100;

//You probably need this if you want to use .LabelFor() 
//and let this property mimic the "full" one  
[Display(Name="Main Biography")]
public string MainBiographyTrimmed
{
    get
    {
        if (this.MainBiography.Length > this.MainBiographyLimit)
            return this.MainBiography.Substring(0, this.MainBiographyLimit) + "...";
        else 
            return this.MainBiography;
    }
}
```

Usage would be

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.MainBiographyTrimmed)
```

Another approach would be to build a full-fledged view model, but I find it overkill more often than not.

Comment: I got an error in the Helper - A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

So I used @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpecialistInterestsTrimmed) and its fine.

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MainBiographyTrimmed)

Comment: @Alex This could also return `string.Format("{0}{1}", this.MainBiography.Substring(0, this.MainBiographyLimit), HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&hellip;"))` for a proper ellipsis.

Answer (score 2):

`DisplayFor` requires an expression that represents a *property*.

You can add a property to the model:

```
public string MainBiographyTrimmed
{
    get
    {
        if (MainBiography.Length > 10 ) { return MainBiography.Substring(0, 10) + "...";}
        else { return MainBiography; }

    }
}
```

Then in your view just do:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.MainBiographyTrimmed)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may write a string extension method and call that on your model property (of string type). You can pass the limit for your substring operation.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SubStringTo(this string thatString, int limit)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(thatString))
        {
            if (thatString.Length > limit)
            {
                return thatString.Substring(0, limit);
            }
            return thatString;
        }
        return string.empty;
    }
}
```

and in your view, import the namespace where you have your extension method and call the method on your string property.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MainBiography.SubStringTo(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Html.Display` instead of `DisplayFor` like this:

```
 @Html.Display(item.MainBiography.Substring(0, 10), null, "MainBiography")
```

By the way your both lambda statements are invalid.Parameter names should be the same.

Not like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MainBiography)
```

It should be:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.MainBiography)
```

Or:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.MainBiography)
```

Comment: If this is in a nested type, he will lose his html field names (prefixes) using `Display`.