# Enter bold tags in razor statement (@)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, view

I am trying to enter bold tags in the following statement but they are not rendering properly.

```
@(user.AlternateId.Count() > 1 ? id.Value  + "<b> ( </b>" + id.Key.Substring(0,3) + "<b> ) </b>"  : id.Value)
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
@if user.AlternateId.Any())
{
    @id.Value <b>(</b> @id.Key.Substring(0,3) <b>)</b>
}
else
{
    @id.Value
}
```

I am hoping that your `id.Key` will always have a length of 3+ chars ,otherwise the call to `SubString` is going to give you an exception. If you are not sure about that ,you might consider writing a custom Substring method (an extension method) which check the string length before trying to do the SubString operation as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860071/40521).

Answer (score 1):

For string values, Razor automatically HTML encodes any HTML. To counter this, you need to convert the string to `IHtmlString`. The easiest way to do that is to just wrap the return in `Html.Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw(user.AlternateId.Count() > 1 ? id.Value  + "<b> ( </b>" + id.Key.Substring(0,3) + "<b> ) </b>"  : id.Value)
```

Alternatively, you can simply create an instance of `MvcHtmlString` (which implements `IHtmlString`):

```
@(new MvcHtmlString(user.AlternateId.Count() > 1 ? id.Value  + "<b> ( </b>" + id.Key.Substring(0,3) + "<b> ) </b>"  : id.Value))
```

For your specific use case, here, `Html.Raw` is more intuitive, but in other scenarios (such as `HtmlHelper` extensions) it can be helpful to know that you can just return an instance of `MvcHtmlString`.